# Suppress Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

Is it possible to suppress a alert dialog with the help of a service or something else outside of the application. I have an application that shows dialogs from time to time. Is there any way I can suppress these dialogs by possibly pressing the positive button "Yes" ?

the dialog I want to suppress come from an application that shows dialogs from time to time that asks the user whether they are still using the app. What I want is to keep running the application without me clicking "Yes" again and again.
So what I was thinking was that to create a service that could suppress this particular alert somehow or all of the alerts of this application.

Comment: you want to suppress another apps alertdialog?

Comment: "Are you sure you want to allow this application to access your contacts/data network/credit card?" Yeah, I can easily imagine many use-cases for such a tool. :-)   But unless you give some more context on what you are doing and how this relates to programming, I vote to close the question as "too broad".

Comment: the dialog I want to suppress come from an application that shows dialogs from time to time that asks the user whether they are still using the app. What I want is to keep running the application without me clicking "Yes" again and again.
So what I was thinking was that to create a service that could suppress this particular alert somehow or all of the alerts of this application.

Comment: @tyczj yes I want to suppress another apps alertdialog.

Comment: You cannot do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If this is simply for testing, I would set an environment variable that you test for when displaying these popup dialog. You could either not pop them up at all or call

```
Button button = progressDialog.getButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON1);
button.click();
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to suppress your own alert. You can't do what you are attempting. It is a big security concern if it was possible